# Not able to get result for def using ruby on mac osx

Tags: ruby, methods

This is just a sample method I have created for testing purpose using Ruby on Mac OSX 10.12 but I don't get the desired output: Can anyone suggest please? I tried getting the result using both paranthesis and without (). It doesn't even throw any error.

```
def hi
puts "Hello World"    
End    
hi    
hi()    
hi("Hello Matz")`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def hi 
  puts "Hello World"
end

hi
hi()
```

And this:

```
def greet(greeting)
  puts greeting
end

greet("Hello Matz")
```

Note that in this line:

```
hi("Hello Matz")`
```

you have a tick mark at the end, so that is an error:

```
1.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected tXSTRING_BEG, expecting end-of-input
```

> It doesn't even throw any error.

Then you aren't running that program.

I suggest you open a Terminal window (Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app), and type in:

```
$ vimtutor
```

vim is a free computer programming editor that comes with your Mac.  Do the tutorial and learn how to use vim.  To run a ruby program, you enter your code into a file, then save it as, say, `my_prog.rb`.  Then you need to give that file to ruby to execute it.  You execute a ruby program like this:

```
$ ruby my_prog.rb
```

You can create a directory for all your ruby programs like this:

```
$ mkdir ruby_programs
$ cd ruby_programs
```

To create a new file inside that directory, use vim:

```
~/ruby_programs$ vi my_prog.rb
```

Once you are done typing in your code, save the file, which will put you back at the prompt in Terminal, then you can run your program:

```
~/ruby_programs$ ruby my_prog.rb
```

Once you get comfortable with vim, and you feel confident running your ruby programs, consider installing macvim with the vivid chalk color scheme:

[image]

It's nicer to look at than plain vim.

Comment: To suggest vim to a beginner... Seriously?

Comment: I tested vim out on 20 monkeys.   For three bananas, two of them were able to bang out Shakespeare by the end of the day

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your file so that it reads:

```
def hi
  puts "Hello World"
end

hi
```

Some important differences to note: `def` and `end` are both case-sensitive. The inside of the function definition is indented by two spaces. Since the function takes no arguments, no parentheses are necessary on the call to `hi` on line 4.

Depending on your filename, enter the command `ruby FILENAME` and you should see the output `Hello World`

Answer (score -1):

Ruby keywords are case sensitive. Your code uses `End` and you probably wanted to use `end` to mark the end of the `hi` method.

Because `End` is not the same as `end` (and `End` is not a keyword), `irb` keeps waiting for input and treats the other three lines as part of the `hi` method. As far as it can tell, its definition is not complete until it reaches the `end` keyword (all non-capital letters.)

The correct way to define the method is:

```
def hi
  puts "Hello World"
end
```

Then you can call it using either `hi` or `hi()`.

Calling it as `hi("Hello Matz")` (or `hi "Hello Matz"`) throws an `ArgumentError` exception with the message `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)` because it is called with one argument but the definition of method `hi` doesn't specify anything about arguments (by its definition, the method `hi` doesn't accept any argument).

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the suggestions. I typed "End" incorrectly as its case sensitive. Now I typed "end" and it worked absolutely fine.

Comment: Another question is reg this below:                                                                                                                       def test(name = "World")
puts "Hello #{name.capitalize}!"
end

What output does this “Hello ##{name.capitalize}” should provide? I am getting to see just “Hello World!”. I am not sure about “name.capitalize”, what it does?

Comment: Take a look at its [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize). It says: *"Returns a copy of `str` with the first character converted to uppercase and the remainder to lowercase."*. It doesn't have any effect on `"World"` because it already has the aforementioned capitalization. If you want the entire word capitalized then try [`upcase`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-upcase).

Comment: ~axiac Thank you!